# Implementing BubbleSort at the end of QuickSort

Tags: java, quicksort, bubble-sort

I finally got my bubblesort and quicksort working but am curious as to how to change my code so that when I reach the last 10 elements being sorted in my quicksort I instead change to bubblesort for faster overhead times.

```
static int num_comps;   

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Random rnd = new Random();

    // max size of array and number of N sets
    int array_size = 32768;
    int num_datasets = 10;

    // array set to max size
    int[] vals = new int[array_size];

    // temporary array with allocated array to max size
    int[] tvals = new int[array_size];

    // array to hold operation counts
    int[] op_counts = new int[num_datasets];
    int[] op_counts2 = new int[num_datasets];

    // array to hold the size of each array
    int[] arraySizes = new int[num_datasets];

    int i;
    int size;

    for (i = 0, size = 64; i < num_datasets; i++, size *= 2)
        arraySizes[i] = size;

    for (int iter = 0; iter < num_datasets; iter++)
    {
        int curr_size = arraySizes[iter];

        // fill array with random values form 0-4999
        for (i = 0; i < curr_size; i++)
            vals[i] = rnd.nextInt(4999);

        //set the temporary array to the actual array
        for (i = 0; i < curr_size; i++)
            tvals[i] = vals[i];

        // run the bubble sort algorithm
        num_comps = 0;
        bubbleSort(tvals, curr_size);
        op_counts[iter] = num_comps;
        //System.out.println("Num comps at " + iter + " is " + num_comps);

        num_comps = 0;
        quickSort(tvals, curr_size);
        op_counts2[iter] = num_comps;
    }

    System.out.println("N     Bubble Sort OP Count  Quick Sort OP Count");
    for (int k = 0; k < num_datasets; k++)
    {
    System.out.println(arraySizes[k] + "\t\t" + op_counts[k] + "\t\t\t" + op_counts2[k]);
    }
}

static void bubbleSort(int vals[], int curr_size)
{
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < curr_size - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < curr_size - i - 1; j++)
        {
            // swap
            num_comps = num_comps + 1;
            if (vals[j+1] < vals[j])
            {
                temp = vals[j];
                vals[j] = vals[j+1];
                vals[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

static void quickSort(int vals[], int curr_size)
{
    quickSort_R(vals, 0, curr_size - 1);
}

static void quickSort_R(int vals[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l < r)
    {
        if ((r-1) == 1) // two elements - trivial sort
        {
            num_comps = num_comps + 1;
            if (vals[l] > vals[r])
                swap(vals, l, r);
            return;
        }

        // partition the elements on the pivot s
        int s = partition(vals, l, r);

        //recurse on the two partitioned values
        quickSort_R(vals, l, s-1);
        quickSort_R(vals, s+1, r);
    }
}

static int partition(int vals[], int l, int r)
{
    int mid = (l+r) / 2;
    int p = medianOfThree(vals, l, r);

    // swap with first element
    swap(vals, l, p);

    int pivot_val = vals[l];
    int i = l;
    int j = r+1;

    do
    {
        num_comps = num_comps + 1;
        do
        {
            i = i + 1;
            num_comps = num_comps + 1;
        } while (vals[i] < pivot_val);
        do
        {
            j = j - 1;
            num_comps = num_comps + 1;
        } while (vals[j] > pivot_val);
        swap(vals, i, j);
    } while (i < j);

    swap(vals, i, j); // undo last swap
    swap(vals, i, j); // put pivot at j, its correct position

    return j;
}

static int medianOfThree(int vals[], int first, int last)
{
    int mid = (first+last) / 2;
    if (vals[first] <= vals[mid] && vals[mid] <= vals[last])
    {
        num_comps = num_comps + 1;
        return mid;
    }
    else if (vals[mid] <= vals[first] && vals[first] <= vals[last])
    {
        num_comps = num_comps + 1;
        return first;
    }
    else
        return last;
}

static void swap(int vals[], int i, int j)
{
    int temp = vals[i];
    vals[i] = vals[j];
    vals[j] = temp;
}
```

}

Comment: Why? Most people use an insertion sort at that point. Bubble sort really has nothing to recommend it except being easy to teach. I've never used one professionally in 37 years, but I've used all the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EJP is right, but if you want to, just modify your code like so:

```
public static void quickSort_R(int vals[], int l, int r) {
    if (l < r) {
        if((r-l) < 10) {
            bubbleSort(vals, r-l); //<--HERE
        }
        else {
            if ((r-1) == 1) { // two elements - trivial sort
                num_comps = num_comps + 1;
                if (vals[l] > vals[r])
                    swap(vals, l, r);
                return;
            }

            // partition the elements on the pivot s
            int s = partition(vals, l, r);

            //recurse on the two partitioned values
            quickSort_R(vals, l, s-1);
            quickSort_R(vals, s+1, r);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm working on my portfolio right now and figured it'd be interesting to compare each algorithm when used with quicksort for smaller lists.